# How to count cells in row with different length based on value of previous cell in row?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I need to make a formula to count how many sessions occurred during user lifetime after session with an event (1).

Each row (user) have different number of sessions.

**0** means an event **didn't occur** during the session of user.

**1** means an event **occurred** during the session of user.

Here is an example of dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HSzkzQm0k-KAlVlAmVO_P86jROYfLwFkPJPKLhtQ7Kg/edit#gid=0

I filled column A3:A with manual counted values.
And now I need help to calculate it with formula. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
=IFERROR(COLUMNS(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(TEXTJOIN(",",true,C3:Y3),"1,(.+)"),",")),0)
```

textjoin+regexextract+split+columns+iferror